# Docker in Jenkins pipeline fails to run due to invalid environment variable: =

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run a docker container in a jenkins pipeline like so:

`agent {
                docker {
                   image 'indiehosters/git'
                   reuseNode true
                }
            }`

but the pipeline fails to run. It seems an invalid environment variable is being set when the docker container is run.

I'm using Jenkins version 2.65, Docker pipeline plugin 1.11, Pipeline plug 2.5

The stacktrace from the Jenkins console:

`java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'indiehosters/git'. Error: invalid argument "=" for e: invalid environment variable: =
See 'docker run --help'.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.run(DockerClient.java:128)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:222)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:148)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:128)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:116)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.DockerPipelineScript.runImage(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/DockerPipelineScript.groovy:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.configureRegistry(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.run(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.checkoutAndRun(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-extensions/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-extensions.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/CheckoutScript.groovy:57)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.doCheckout(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-extensions/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-extensions.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/CheckoutScript.groovy:40)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript.run(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/LabelScript.groovy:45)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor396.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:173)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:162)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: What is the image command? Could you try to only do echo "Test" and see if that works? I think image 'indiehosters/git' is not a valid pipeline command. Checkout SCM would pull from git

Comment: I am using the declarative pipeline where image tells Jenkins what Docker image to run, so for example here I am running an Docker image with git installed. I tested it using a different image, same error again.

Answer (score 7):

Ok solved it.

Basically, there was an empty environment variable set in Jenkins. Removed the empty variable and it worked!

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/pull/101